# Sharepoint - document

Tags: workflow-history

When I click on send to - download a copy - (I click on open not save), I edit the file, and I saved, when I look at after, I not finding.

Already look on the folder ~TEMP and didn't found.

Could anyone help? does it save in somewhere else?

thanks.

Comment: 3 questions: Is the document updated on SharePoint? Is it in your downloads folder? When you "click on send to - download a copy - (I click on open not save)" for another document, choose Save As..., what is the default directory?